# How to make border like small line between the views?

Tags: android

I want to make border in android layout like this , how can I do that ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For show like the above output image

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eeeeee"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="E"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="F"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have new question like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539670/i-want-to-make-separator-like-the-following

Answer (score 3):

If you want a customize separator, make separator.xml in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#ffffffff"
        android:endColor="#00ffffff"
        android:startColor="#00ffffff" />

</shape>
```

then refer to this separator shape with this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="2dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
    android:src="@drawable/seperator" />
```

result:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by putting three `Views` with the colors you want

like

```
<View
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="1dip"
android:background="#f3f3f3"
/>
```

Comment: layout_height="match_parent", but otherwise I agree. ImageView is more versatile; but this lightweight and easy if you don't want anything fancy.

Comment: but I have  android:layout_width="0px"                 
                android:layout_weight="1" to make all views have the same amount of space

Comment: @forsubhi dont put any weight for this view i have tried it with  my codes working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

To create a border in android we have to use stroke tag in shape ( xml drawable )

Here is my code which I have tested at my end :

stroke_background.xml

```
    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>


</shape>
```

layout you require

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".5" 
        android:background="@drawable/stroke_background">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="E" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:background="@drawable/stroke_background"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
         >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="F" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Result look like this..
[image]